# popAndReplacement shows page which is behind the poping page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There are 3 screens in my app. When I use popAndPushNamed() in the 2nd page, it pops the 2nd page and shows the 3rd page, but when It pops it shows the 1st page behind it in milliseconds. how to avoid that?

1. is Animation the way?
2. or are there any other methods just like push and show 3rd page, and pop 2nd page when the 3rd page visible to the user?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushReplacement.html - It waits until the new route has finished animating before disposing the previous one.

Comment: yes.. it works, slightly it shows my first page and shows 2nd page.

Comment: is there any other way to push 3rd page. when it completes pop 2nd page.

Comment: "Replace the current route of the navigator by pushing the given route and then disposing the previous route once the new route has finished animating in." - It's strange that the first page is visible for a split second. According to this sentence in their documentation, it should not happen. Can you post the code you have written?

Comment: Navigator.of(this.context)
          .popAndPushNamed(routeName, arguments: id);

Comment: when it pop the page, first screen is left in the stack. that's why it shows for a split second

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popAndPushNamed.html Here is the documentation for pop and push named "The animations for the pop and the push are performed simultaneously, so the route below may be briefly visible even if both the old route and the new route are opaque". This is mentioned here. Try replacing it with Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(routeName, arguments: id);

Comment: Yes ...It works..Thanks @Afridi Kayal

Comment: write it as an answer, I will upvote and select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

popAndPushNamed() as the documentation suggests, pushes the new route but pops the old route simultaneously, and hence, there is a small moment where you can see the first page even if your new routes are fully opaque. Replace the method with Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed() and it should work as expected.